# MVC Delete Get v POST ambiguous method signiture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, software-design

My Controller has a Delete method, in fact it has two, the GET and the POST.

Both these need only an id to work, so I end up with an ambiguous method i.e.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(string id) { ... }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(string id) { ... }
```

Is there a *best practise* for handling this?

In case there was any doubt, the `[HttpGet]` method returns the object to be deleted so the user can confirm, the `[HttpPost]` performs the deletion and redirects to the `Index` action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ActionName attribute to specify your action name differently than the controller method name:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(string id) { ... }

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id) { ... }
```